# Opening Android Emulator with an existing project

Tags: flutter

I need to reopen the Android Emulator with my existing project. When I press the button to "run" the project from the main file, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\albat\code\hello_world\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx' after 10 attempts

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Also, instead of the "Pixel 2 API" device, that I always use, it tried to render with "sdk gphone x86".

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

from android studio find android AVD manger. it will show you a list of all your emulators.
choose one and click run.
wait for it to boot up then try running your app again.

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: sorry, no it's not working. I  think it might be because in the file "AndroidManifest.xml" I do not have the code for the internet permition. Could it be? and if so, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Open AVD manager and choose your emulator.

If your running app shows any error. delete your unnecessary previous app.

then run again and solved your current problem.

Please checked `local.properties` file in your app folder. If this file is not existing then create `local.properties` and add your sdk link

```
sdk.dir=/Users/<yourUserName>/Library/Android/sdk.
```